# Required String parameter 'firstdropdown' is not present

Tags: html, spring-boot

I'm new to SpringBoot. I'm trying to make a small app which uploads csv files in directory of my choice. For this purpose, the user would fill a small form with two fields - issue type and granularity. According to what user selects, the file would be uploaded in that directory. For example, if a user selects issue to be loan and granularity to be weekly, the file would be stored in `C:\Users\loan\weekly`.

Here is my code:

UploadingController.java.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class UploadingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dropdown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView user() { 
       Dropdown dropdown = new Dropdown();
       dropdown.setIssue("Loan");
       dropdown.setGranularity("Daily");
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("dropdown", "command", dropdown);
      return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addDropdown", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Dropdown dropdown, 
       ModelMap model) {
       model.addAttribute("issue", dropdown.getIssue());
       model.addAttribute("granularity", dropdown.getGranularity());   
       return "dropdown";
    }
    @ModelAttribute("firstdropdown")
    public Map<String, String> getFirstDropdown() {
       Map<String, String> firstdropdown = new HashMap<String, String>();
       firstdropdown.put("Loan", "Loan");
       firstdropdown.put("Lease", "Lease");
       firstdropdown.put("Other", "Other");
       return firstdropdown;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("seconddropdown")
    public Map<String, String> getSecondDropdown() {
       Map<String, String> seconddropdown = new HashMap<String, String>();
       seconddropdown.put("Daily", "Daily");
       seconddropdown.put("Weekly", "Weekly");
       seconddropdown.put("Monthly", "Monthly");
       return seconddropdown;
    }

    public static String uploadingDir = System.getProperty("user.home");

    @GetMapping("/uploading")
    public String uploading(Model model) {
        File file = new File(uploadingDir);
        model.addAttribute("files", file.listFiles());
        return "uploading";
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploading-post")
    public String uploadingPost(@RequestParam("uploadingFiles") MultipartFile uploadingFiles, 
                                @RequestParam("firstdropdown") String firstdropdown, 
                                @RequestParam("seconddropdown") String seconddropdown) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(uploadingDir + uploadingFiles.getOriginalFilename());
        uploadingFiles.transferTo(file);

        return "redirect:/dropdown"; // redirect accordingly
    }

}
```

And, this is how I tweaked uploading.ftl by adding the following block of code. It works perfectly fine as an HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Uploading Files Example with Spring Boot, Freemarker</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="updateSize();">
        <form name="uploadingForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="POST">
        <select name="mydropdown">
<option value="Blank"> </option>
<option value="Loan">Loan</option>
<option value="Lease">Lease</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<select name="seconddropdown">
<option value="Blank"> </option>
<option value="Daily">Daily</option>
<option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
<option value="Monthly">Monthy</option>
</select>
            <p>
                <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="uploadingFiles" onchange="updateSize();" multiple>
                selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>;
                total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload files">
            </p>
        </form>
        <div>
            <div>Uploaded files:</div>
            <#list files as file>
            <div>
            ${file.getName()}
            </div>
            </#list>
        </div>
        <script>
            function updateSize() {
                var nBytes = 0,
                        oFiles = document.getElementById("fileInput").files,
                        nFiles = oFiles.length;
                for (var nFileId = 0; nFileId < nFiles; nFileId++) {
                    nBytes += oFiles[nFileId].size;
                }

                var sOutput = nBytes + " bytes";
                // optional code for multiples approximation
                for (var aMultiples = ["KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB"], nMultiple = 0, nApprox = nBytes / 1024; nApprox > 1; nApprox /= 1024, nMultiple++) {
                    sOutput = nApprox.toFixed(3) + " " + aMultiples[nMultiple] + " (" + nBytes + " bytes)";
                }
                // end of optional code

                document.getElementById("fileNum").innerHTML = nFiles;
                document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = sOutput;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dropdown.java class:

```
package com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles;

public class Dropdown {
    private String issue;
    private String granularity;
    public String getIssue() {
        return issue;
    }
    public void setIssue(String issue) {
        this.issue = issue;
    }
    public String getGranularity() {
        return granularity;
    }
    public void setGranularity(String granularity) {
        this.granularity = granularity;
    }

}
```

And Application.Java :

```
package com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new File(UploadingController.uploadingDir).mkdirs();
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The DropdownController.java class:

```
package com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller("/dropdown")
public class DropDownController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/issueTypes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> getFirs() {
        Map<String, String> firstdropdown = new HashMap<String, String>();
        firstdropdown.put("issueTypes", "Loan, Lease, Ranl");
        return firstdropdown;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/granularities", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> getGranularity() {
        Map<String, String> granularities = new HashMap<String, String>();
        granularities.put("granularities", "Daily, Weekly ,Monthly");
        return granularities;
    }

}
```

Application.properties file:

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path: /
spring.freemarker.suffix: .ftl
issue.type=Loan,Leas,Rank
report.granularity=Daily,Weekly,Monthly
```

The error I'm getting:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [dropdown]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/dropdown] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: You have used same requestMapping name "/" for each of the different methods. Use different names for each of the mappings.

Comment: I changed last two RequestMapping to /upload and now I'm getting Request method 'POST' not supported @Samim

Comment: You will get `POST not supported` error when a particular parameter is missing.

Comment: if the answer helped you solving your problem then you can upvote and accept the answer as solution

Comment: also post the error stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your HTML code. You are having two different forms for posting the form.
Correct it like:

```
    <form action="/" method="GET">

        <input list="firstdropdown" name="firstdropdown">
        <datalist id="firstdropdown">
            <option value="Loan">Loan</option>
            <option value="Lease">Lease</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </datalist>

        <input list="seconddropdown" name="seconddropdown">
        <datalist id="seconddropdown">
            <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
            <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
            <option value="Monthly">Monthy</option>
        </datalist>

        <button type="submit">SEND DATA</button>

    </form>
```

**UPDATE**

update your controller like:

```java
@Controller
public class UploadingController {

    public static String vary;
    public static String uploadingDir = System.getProperty("user.home") + vary;

    @GetMapping("/dir")
    @ResponseBody
    public String dir(@RequestParam("firstdropdown") String firstdropdown, 
                      @RequestParam("seconddropdown") String seconddropdown) {
        vary = "/" + firstdropdown + "/" + seconddropdown + "/";
        return vary;
    }

    @GetMapping("/uploading")
    public String uploading(Model model) {
        File file = new File(uploadingDir);
        model.addAttribute("files", file.listFiles());
        return "uploading";
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploading-post")
    public String uploadingPost(@RequestParam("uploadingFiles[]") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles, 
                                @RequestParam("firstdropdown") String firstdropdown, 
                                @RequestParam("seconddropdown") String seconddropdown) throws IOException {

        for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
            File file = new File(uploadingDir + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
            uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
        }

        return "redirect:/uploading"; // redirect accordingly
    }
}
```

change in your HTML like:

```
<p>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" accept=".csv,text/csv" name="uploadingFiles[]" onchange="updateSize();">
    selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>;
    total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span>
</p>
```

**UPDATE**

apply these settings in your `application.properties` files

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
```

if you are using spring security then ignore that mapping like:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    String[] ignoredCsrfMappings = {"/file-test"};
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(ignoredCsrfMappings);
    // rest of your settings
}
```

Some changes to your mapping

```java
   @PostMapping("/uploading-post", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String uploadingPost(@RequestParam("uploadingFiles[]") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles, 
                                @RequestParam("firstdropdown") String firstdropdown, 
                                @RequestParam("seconddropdown") String seconddropdown) throws IOException {

        for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
            File file = new File(uploadingDir + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
            uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
        }

        return "redirect:/uploading"; // redirect accordingly
    }
```

Now it should work.

Comment: It's still giving the same error. That firstdropdown is not present.

Comment: @jukebox if you have any more codes than this then kindly update your question.

Comment: Done. I added all the code. The rest of the code is the same as the link provided.

Comment: Done. Please take a look now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193882/discussion-between-jukebox-and-samim).

Comment: I have put the entire code. It would be great if you could take a look at it and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I have added error as well now. Please take a look.

Comment: I haven't used FreeMaker. I use Thymeleaf. Your error seems to point out to your view. `javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [dropdown]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/dropdown] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
`